# can I feed a placeholder whti tf.train.Supervisor

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I use `tf.train.Supervisor` to manager my training session. I use dataset to feed input to my network. Now I need define a placeholder in my network. I found out that I can't feed this placeholder to my network. I tried passing the following to `Supervisor`: `init_feed_dict`.

```
__init__(
    graph=None,
    ready_op=USE_DEFAULT,
    ready_for_local_init_op=USE_DEFAULT,
    is_chief=True,
    init_op=USE_DEFAULT,
    init_feed_dict=None,
    local_init_op=USE_DEFAULT,
    logdir=None,
    summary_op=USE_DEFAULT,
    saver=USE_DEFAULT,
    global_step=USE_DEFAULT,
    save_summaries_secs=120,
    save_model_secs=600,
    recovery_wait_secs=30,
    stop_grace_secs=120,
    checkpoint_basename='model.ckpt',
    session_manager=None,
    summary_writer=USE_DEFAULT,
    init_fn=None
)
```

But it didn't work, is there any solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, eventually you should post some code.

But regardless of that you define a placeholder

`my_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=my_shapes)`

that defines an input tensor to your model and

than if running your `tf.Graph` in a `tf.Session` you can feed your input placeholder with values

`feed_dict = {my_input: my_values}`

In your case, using the `tf.train.Supervisor()` managed session you can feed these values at its `init_feed_dict`.

Comment: ok. I will post some working example. but as I said, init_feed_dict don't work. I check the code. the init_feed_dict only feed to init_op. not my graph.